# Finding range of a trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$$f(x) = \frac{\tan^{2}(x) - 1}{\tan(x)}$$
I want to find the range of this function.
I have gone as far as figuring out that the range of
$\tan^{2}(x) - 1$ is $[-1, \infty)$ and that of
$\tan(x)$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$. How do I go about finding the range of the whole function?
I would prefer not to use graphs, but rather resort to a purely algebraic proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $$\frac{\tan^{2}(x) - 1}{\tan(x)} = \frac{1}{\tan x} \frac{\sin ^{2} x  - \cos^{2} x}{\cos^{2}x} = - \frac{\cos 2x} {\sin x \cos x}  = - 2 \cdot \frac{\cos 2x} {\sin 2x} = -2 \cot 2x$$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan^2x-f(x)\tan y-1=0$$

is a quadratic equation in $\tan x$ which is real, so the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$$\implies f^2(x)+4\ge0$$ which is true for all real $f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

We can write $f(x)$ as $y-\frac 1 y$ where $y=\tan x$. The equation $y-\frac 1 y=z$ has  solution for every real number $z$: $y=\frac {z \pm \sqrt {z^{2}+4}} 2$. This gives $f(\arctan y)=z$ proving that the range of the function is the entire real line.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$f(x)=\tan(x)-\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$
$$=-2\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}$$
$$=\frac{-2}{\tan(2x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write:
$$
f(x)=tan(x)-cot(x)
$$

Now it is clear as $x \rightarrow 0^+$, $f(x)$ will approach $-\infty$ and as $x \rightarrow  {\frac{\pi}{2}^-}$, $f(x)$ will approach $\infty$